# Flask / Python / WTForms validation and dynamically set SelectField choices

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm trying to create a simple `Flask` / `Python` one page web app that uses dynamically created choices for a SelectField.

However, I can't get it to POST using dynamically created choices, and there's also some funny validation behaviour going on (will explain after the code)

I created a minimum failing example here:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import IntegerField, SubmitField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, NumberRange, Optional

# Set up app and config    
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = '42721564'
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# Main stuff starts here

class SelectFieldForm(Form):
    default_field = SelectField('Default Set SelectField', choices=[(i, i) for i in range(0,60,5)], coerce=int)
    default_field_2 = SelectField('Default Set SelectField', choices=[(i, i) for i in range(0,60,5)], coerce=int)
    dynamic_field = SelectField('Dynamically Set Selectfield', choices=[], validators=[Optional()], coerce=int)

    get_default_field_value_difference = SubmitField(label='Get Default Field Difference')
    deduct_dynamic_field_value = SubmitField(label='Deduct Dynamic Field Value')


@app.route('/mfe-dynamic-selectfield', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def failingSelectField():
    form = SelectFieldForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("validated")

        difference = form.default_field_2.data - form.default_field.data

        if form.get_default_field_value_difference.data:
            flash( difference )
            form.dynamic_field.choices = [(i,i) for i in range(0,difference,5)]

            return render_template('mfe-dynamic-selectfield.html', form=form)

        if form.deduct_dynamic_field_value.data:

            if form.dynamic_field.data:
                deducted = difference - form.dynamic_field.data
                flash( deducted )

            else:
                flash( "no dynamic field value chosen")           

            return render_template('mfe-dynamic-selectfield.html', form=form)

        else:
            flash( "nope" )

    return render_template('mfe-dynamic-selectfield.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Bringing up the page works just fine, and immediately flashes "nope", as expected.

Calculating the difference between the default set fields:
-works every time as long they are both set to '0'
-if either field is not set to '0', every other POST fails validation, and the time correctly calculates the difference and dynamically sets the last field.

Trying to POST using the dynamically set field fails every time.

Am I missing something very obvious here?

I'm rendering using this:

```
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post" name="mfe-dynamic-selectfield">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  <table>
  <tr>
      <td> Calculated value </td>
      <td>

      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
          {% if messages %}
            <ul class=flashes>
            {% for message in messages %}
              <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          {% endif %}
       {% endwith %}

       </td>
  </tr>

  <br>
  <tr>
      <td>Default SelectField 1</td>
      <td>Default SelectField 2</td>

      <td>Dynamic Selectfield</td>
  </tr>

  <br>

  <tr>
      <td>{{ form.default_field }}</td>
      <td>{{ form.default_field_2 }}</td>

      <td>{{ form.dynamic_field }}</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
      <td>{{ form.get_default_field_value_difference }}</td>
      <td>{{ form.deduct_dynamic_field_value }}</td>
  </tr>      

  </table>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing every other time because the value of `form.dynamic_field` is oscillating between `0` and `None`. The form passes validation only when the value is `None`.

This is because `form.dynamic_field.choices` is `[]` (an empty list) at the time of validation. So any value that comes there is rejected. You probably want to dynamically set the choices *before* you try the validating; maybe with something like this:

```
@app.route('/mfe-dynamic-selectfield', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def failingSelectField():
    form = SelectFieldForm()

    # Calculate dynamic field choices
    try:
        difference = form.default_field_2.data - form.default_field.data
        form.dynamic_field.choices = [(i,i) for i in range(0,difference,5)]
    except TypeError:
        pass

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # (continue as usual)
```

Now the form will validate as expected.

Of course, you should probably add some code in front to make sure that the `default_field`s do have valid choices values (not just any two integers). Another option is to put `dynamic_field` in a second form. Then you can validate the first form, and use its values to calculate valid choices for the second one.

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm.

So with my limited understanding of how validation works, this basically checks the static fields and sets the dynamic field and then validates the form on every POST / GET.

Previously, on a POST I'd pass the value for the dynamic field back and re-render the form, but it wouldn't be set on the new form before it tried to be validated, so it failed...? this is still the part I don't quite get.

Comment: Before trying to validate the form, you have to specify what the valid choices are. It doesn't "remember" the choices you set last time because you start with a new `SelectFieldForm` every time the page is loaded/submitted to. Check out https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/forms.html for an introduction to forms and validation.

Comment: I think I get it. The documentation doesn't really cover this case, but let me see if I can explain how I understand it in a logical way. The `try:` section sets the valid choices on the new `SelectFieldForm` because otherwise we would be trying to submit, validating against no-valid-choices. I want to keep the app to one page, is there a less clunky way-- maybe one that doesn't start with a new form everytime the page is loaded/submitted to?